# Primefaces error messages not dissappears on submit

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form with following fields.While click on submit button I am getting error messages if fields are null.But when I filled the fields and click on submit again, neither the error messages goes nor the form get submitted.Please go through the code.It is a primefaces wizard component.in case of 'Next' button no issue reported.

```
<p:wizard flowListener="#{employeeRepositoryImpl.handleFlow}"
    showNavBar="true" widgetVar="scheduler" showStepStatus="false"
    style="ui-wizard-nav-next">

    <p:tab id="personal">
        <p:panel header="Login Credentials">


            <h:panelGrid columns="3" autoUpdate="false">

                <h:outputText value="First Name*" />
                <p:inputText value="#{myBean.firstName}" required="true"
                    label="First Name" id="firstName"
                    validatorMessage="Invalid First Name">
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message id="msg4" for="firstName" display="text" />

                <h:outputText value="Middle Name" />
                <p:inputText value="#{myBean.middleName}" label="Middle Name"
                    id="middleName" />
                <p:message id="msg5" for="middleName" display="text" />

                <h:outputText value="Last Name*" />
                <p:inputText value="#{myBean.lastName}" required="true"
                    label="Last Name" id="lastName"
                    validatorMessage="Invalid Last Name">
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message id="msg6" for="lastName" display="text" />

            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="user">
        <p:panel header="Other">
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
</p:wizard>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{myBean.save}"
    update="msg4 msg5 msg6">
</p:commandButton>
```

I am using JSF2+Primefaces.3.0.M3+Prettyfaces-jsf2.3.3.2 with GAE.

Comment: Are you sure the form does not get submitted? Do you have `<h:form>` surrounding all the components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an ajax update of the message component like this

```
<p:inputText value="#{myBean.lastName}" required="true"
                label="Last Name" id="lastName"
                validatorMessage="Invalid Last Name">
      <p:ajax update="msg6" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message id="msg6" for="lastName" display="text" />
```

After that see if you have any more errors. I think there are some left and you were not able to distinguish them with the previous messages that is why the form is not getting submitted.